# Cannot delete file that "does not exist" according to Windows-7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Somehow a file ended up on the personal desktop of my Windows 7 machine that does not actually exist. I recognize the title as part of a Reddit post, but I don't know how it ended up on my desktop. The file is listed when using the `dir` command, but it has 0 bytes and cannot be renamed or deleted through normal means. I get a "File does not exist" or "Could not find this item" in every method I've tried.

[Windows Error Dialog on delete attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjz2w.png)

I have tried everything I can think of.

- Rebooting my computer and hard shutdown, file is still there when booted back up
- Deleting/Renaming the file using the standard right click menu
- Command Prompt to delete/rename the file
- Administrator command prompt to delete/rename the file
- Killing `explorer.exe` in the task menu, then using the administrator command prompt to delete/rename the file
- Using `fsutil file createnew <file> 0` on the same file name, created a second file I could delete but the original is still there.

I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe try booting a live OS such as Ubuntu on CD or USB, then mount the Windows partition and delete that file?

Comment: The filename has probably unprintable (and therefore invisible) chars in it. Try to use wildcards: instead of `del name` use `del *n*a*m*e*`. Be carefule though that you don't delete other files!

Comment: Are you sure it is on YOUR desktop, not the common "All Users"'s desktop, which is shown superimposed with your own? i.e. look in "c:\Users\All Users\Desktop" in addition to your own "C:\Users\yourname\Desktop" . I don't think this is your problem, but it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

start, find cmd, open
del "%userprofile%\desktop\FirstFewLetters*.*" /f
?